# Conditional: current user updated post in the last X days

Tags: conditional-tags, date-time

I'm trying to find a **native WP function solution** to this other solution...

> I'm looking for a conditional whereby it checks to see if the current
>   user has updated their custom post (CUSTOMPOST) within that last X
>   days (or hours). If they have updated do this, if they haven't updated
>   do that, else do whatever.

SQL solution

```
global $wpdb;
$pre=$wpdb->prefix;
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-1 days"));
$userid=get_current_user_id();
$sql="SELECT p.ID FROM ".$pre."posts as p WHERE p.post_modified >= '".$date."' AND  p.post_author='".$userid."' AND p.post_type='CUSTOMPOST'";
$modpost=$wpdb->query($sql);
if($modpost){ 

    //Do what you need to do

}
```

Comment: Must the current user be the original post author?

Comment: Elaboration: Every user publishes a single CPT post. When a user visits the website I want that user to be restricted according to how recently they have updated their CPT post - for example I can add the above code in page.php to restrict a user viewing specific content on all pages. 

In answer to your question, the current user doesn't need to be the original author (or otherwise), they just need to have updated their own CPT post within x days.

Consider this snippet as a "gate-keeper" - no one can see the fruit bowl unless they have a banana that is no older than X days. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that in my previous answer I focused on duplicating your current SQL query but your query is not what your question's text says.

One condition seems to be that the current user must be the original author.

If the revision history exists, then we would need to find out the who authored the parent post for each revision.

Instead of going down that road, I think you should consider storing that  information in the user meta table.

There exists the `_last_edit` post meta key to determine who last modified each post. This is e.g. used in [`get_the_modified_author()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_modified_author/) function.

My suggestion is therefore to store a similar `_wpse_last_modified_cpt` user meta key with the unix modification time as a value, each time when the cpt is updated.

Then you can fetch it for the current user and check if the stored datetime is within the wanted limit.

*I hope I'm understanding the question correctly ;-)*

**Previous Answer:**

It sounds like you're looking for this kind of query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    [
        'post_type'     => 'cpt',                       // Adjust to your needs!
        'fields'        => 'ids',
        'author'        => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'date_query'    => [
            [
                'after'     => '7 days ago midnight',  // Adjust to your needs!
                'inclusive' => true,
                'column'    => 'post_modified'         
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

that generates this kind of a `WHERE` part of the SQL:

```
WHERE 1=1 
    AND ( wp_posts.post_modified >= '2016-09-09 00:00:00' ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_author IN (123) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'cpt' 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

You should then add a `is_user_logged_in()` check before running the query.

Then you can use e.g. this kind of check:

```
if( $query->have_posts() )
{
      // Do what you need to do!
}
```

to see if a custom post, written by the current user, has been updated within the last `n` days.